# Want to create Excel file with multiple wroksheets in PHP

Tags: php, excel

i want to export data into excel i am using this and it is working but it create one file with one worksheet. i want to create multiple worksheet is there any way?

**i don't want to use PHPExcel plugin.**

is there way to do this?

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$flag = false;
        while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if(!$flag) {
              // display field/column names as first row
              echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
              $flag = true;
            }
            echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
        }
```

Comment: Why avoid using PHPExcel ? Just curious .

Comment: no specific reason. i just don't want to use any plugin this might drag me to learn new things.

Comment: Your approach is not creating a Excel file but a Text file with tabulator delimited content. Excel has default import routines which will open such files. But you have seen that this is limited to only one sheet. PHPExcel can create really Excel files and it is open source. So look at this source "to learn new things".